# Display MySQL JOIN in PHP results

Tags: php, mysql

I have added a recordset that successfully performs a JOIN on an existing results page:

```
mysql_select_db($database_redcross, $redcross);
$query_idToClient = "SELECT clientLName, clientFName FROM sys_client LEFT JOIN sys_visits USING (clientID)";
$idToClient = mysql_query($query_idToClient, $redcross) or die(mysql_error());
$row_idToClient = mysql_fetch_assoc($idToClient);
$totalRows_idToClient = mysql_num_rows($idToClient);
```

The result page also queries another table called sys_visits and displays results like this currently:

```
<table class="WADAResultsTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">clientID:</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $WARRT_AltClass1->getClass(true); ?>">

      <td class="WADAResultsTableCell">

      <a href="sys_visits_Detail.php?pid=<?php echo(rawurlencode($row_WADAsys_visits['pid'])); ?>" ><?php echo($row_WADAsys_visits['clientID']); ?></a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_WADAsys_visits = mysql_fetch_assoc($WADAsys_visits)); ?>
</table>
```

How do I echo the matching clientFName and clientLname from the recordset instead of just the id.  The clientID is the same same in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($idToClient)) 
{
   echo "clientLName: " .$row[0] . "clientFName: " .$row[1];
}
```

Comment: So close!  That shows ALL records, I only want the one for that row in the results?

Comment: Then change your SQL to only fetch one. Don't do lots of work in your database only to throw the data away in PHP

Comment: You just want the details for a specific user id? Then you should add a where query on your SQL e.g(SELECT clientLName, clientFName FROM sys_client LEFT JOIN sys_visits USING (clientID) WHERE clientID = xxxx)

Comment: The records are displayed in a loop based on a dynamic query from a search form, I only want to switch out the id for the name which is not in the table sys_visits table.  I updated the question with the whole results section.

Comment: This did the trick in the context of the question I asked.  Thanks!